# Stochastic matrix relating to power method

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I dont quite understand this question that I am doing some practice questions for and was wondering if someone could help explain it.

The question is a s follows:

"Let $P$ be the stochastic matrix given by: $$ P = \left[ 
\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]$$

The matrix $P$ has six distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = 1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_6$ with $\left| \lambda_i \right| < 1$ for $i = 2,3,4,5,6$. Let $v_1, \ldots, v_6$ be the corresponding eigenvectors. What is $v_1$ ? If $X_0 = c_1v_1 + \ldots + c_6v_6$. Write down a formula for the probability of winning after $n$ steps in terms of $n, \lambda_i, v_i$ and $c_i$."

I know that $$v_1 = \left[ \begin{matrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right]$$ but what I don't understand is how to write the probability of winning after $n$ steps in terms of $c_i$.

The first thought that came to my mind was the idea of diagonalization and writing $$P^nx_0 = UD^nU^T$$and then $$P^nx_0 = UD^nU^Tx_0$$but then I couldn't figure out how to include the coefficients.

Would someone mind explaining or helping me out please ?

Advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that $X_0 = \sum_{i}c_iv_i$, we have
$$
X_1 = PX_0 = \sum_{i}c_iPv_i=\sum_ic_i\lambda_iv_i
$$
and
$$
X_2 = PX_1 = \sum_{i}c_i\lambda_iPv_i=\sum_ic_i\lambda_i^2v_i
$$
More generally,
$$
X_n = P^nX_0=\sum_ic_i\lambda_i^nv_i
$$
Finally, we normalize $X_n$ such that its components constitute a probability, i.e., their sum is $1$.

Comment: Oh I see, so we used the fact that $Pv_i = \lambda_i v_i$ and since $x$ is in the span of the eigenvectors, then we can thus write it as the span of the eigenvectors times some $\lambda_i^n$ right ?

Comment: @PutsandCalls Yes.